# Typescript: Is it possible to reference type aliases

Tags: javascript, typescript

Typescript allows us to use string literals as types. The question is can I reference them with the dot-notation? For example I have a type like this

```
export type SomeTypes = 'OPEN' | 'CLOSED' | 'PROGRESSED' | 'DONE';
```

Can I somehow use it like this?

```
if(typecheck === SomeTypes.OPEN)
```

Right now I have to write out the string literal which is not entirely the type safety way. It looks like this

```
if(typecheck === 'OPEN')
```

Comment: No, string literals are just strings, there's no object that wraps them. It's only that the compiler checks a value against the specific values specified for the string literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [TypeScript 2.4](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html) - it supports String Enumerations.

Apart from that (since 2.4 introduces breaking changes) a more expressive "workaround" is as follows - define the constants as variables and then provide the alias upon the constants:

```
export const SOME_TYPE_OPEN = 'OPEN';
export const SOME_TYPE_CLOSED = 'CLOSED';
...
export type SomeType = SOME_TYPE_OPEN | SOME_TYPE_CLOSED | ...;
```

Then you can use:

```
function getIt(value: SomeType) {
    if (SOME_TYPE_OPEN === value) { ... }
    ...
}
```